# How to generate a sourcemap for an extracted code snippet

Tags: javascript, node.js, code-snippets, source-maps, transpiler

I have these template files I'm extracting code from. They're a lot like a vue template file
`someView.html:`

```
<title>Editor View</title>

<config>
  <window width=512 height=512 target="main" />
  <load pre="default" modCode=true modCss=true />
</config>

<body>
  <h1>Editor</h1>
  ...
</body>

<style>
  h1 {
     background: black;
     color: white;
     /*...*/
  }
</style>

<script>
  let test = 'confirmed';
  console.log(test);
</script>
```

Obviously this isn't passing any html linter tests but all I am doing is extracting the contents of each tag and using them to construct a page on the fly in Electron. The only issue is, I'd like that `console.log()` or any errors produced by the script, to show this file in the inspector via sourcemapping, as well as point to this file when inspecting css rules, but I'm not too experienced with this.

### Update:

I found this library [`source-map-dummy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-dummy), and I've spent some time trying to adapt it to my needs. Right now I have the following

```
import path from "path"
import fs from "fs"

import jsTokens from "js-tokens"
import cssTokens from "css-tokens"

import { SourceMapGenerator } from "source-map"


const blank = /^\s*$/
const newline = /\r\n?|\n/


export default function createSourceMap(input, options = {}) {
  if (!options.source) {
    throw new Error("`options.source` is required. Got: " + options.source)
  }

  let tokens

  if (typeof input === "string") {
    switch (options.type) {
      case "js":
        tokens = input.match(jsTokens)
        break
      case "css":
        tokens = input.match(cssTokens)
        break
      default:
        throw new Error("You must set `options.type` to either `js` or `css`. Got: " + options.type)
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error("A string of JavaScript or CSS is required. Got: " + input)
  }

  let code = fs.readFileSync(options.source, "utf8"),
      localSource = options.source.slice(options.source.indexOf("view")),
      map = new SourceMapGenerator({
        file: __dirname
      }),

      line = 1,
      lineOffset,

      column = 0,
      columnOffset,

      codeLines = code.split(newline),
      indexLine = input.split(newline)[1]

  for(let c in codeLines) {
    let codeLine = codeLines[c],
        i = codeLine.indexOf(indexLine)

    if(i != -1) {
      lineOffset = parseInt(c)
      columnOffset = parseInt(i)
    }
  }

  tokens.forEach(function(token) {
    if (blank.test(token)) return;

    map.addMapping({
      generated: {
        line: line,
        column: column
      },
      original: {
        line: line + lineOffset,
        column: column + columnOffset
      },
      source: localSource
    })

    let lines = token.split(newline),
        lastLine = lines.pop(),
        addedLines = lines.length

    if (addedLines) {
      line += addedLines
      column = lastLine.length
    } else {
      column += lastLine.length
    }
  })

  return map
}
```

This almost works for the CSS, it at least shows up though only the first rule gets the proper line number??, but the Javascript side is not recognized by the Dev Tools, and I can't figure out why. I'm pretty much at a loss at this point.